# Does Ebean support multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, orm, ebean

The Ebean ORM is the go-to ORM for the Play! Java Framework.
As I am making the choice between building my own object relational mappers and other object relational behavioural patterns, and using an ORM, a criterion that strikes me as really important is whether or not Ebeans supports concurrent access to mappers.
Indeed albeit Play! uses asynchronous threading, there can still be a reader/writer problem that arises from concurrent requests using the same objects.

Hence the question is, do the Ebean ORM supports multithreading (reader/writer problem)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ebeans supports concurrent access to mappers

EbeanServer is safe for multiple concurrent use yes. The EbeanServer instance is built and contains all the meta data about the bean properties etc (so the mapping information).

EbeanServer internally holds some mutating data such as L2 cache, performance metrics for query execution, query execution plans etc but these are written to be thread safe.

In general Query objects and query results (object graphs) are not thread safe and intended for single threaded use.  You can create read-only object graphs that can't be mutated and hence safe for multi-threaded use via query.setReadOnly(true).

EbeanServer also has support for background fetching via findFutureRowCount(), findFutureList() etc which internally makes a copy of the query and takes care of the details.  findFutureRowCount() is used internally as part of PagedList to get total row count.

Comment: Great, thanks for the thorough answer! Is there anywhere I can find documentation regarding the matter? Thanks again!

Comment: Well there is http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/ and http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/features/l2caching .  If you have questions about specific features then perhaps log a documentation issue or ask on the google group or here (but I don't always see questions raised on SO).